# how to find the service which has modified a file?

Tags: command-line, files

I have 3 services files running on my ubuntu and binaries are stored in `/usr/sbin`. And services are running under `root` user. There is a file stored at `/var` folder and one of the service is modifying this file. How to find out which service/binary is modifying this file ? Is there any command in linux ?

I tried using find command but it helps to see whether files is modified or not? It wont help to see who has modified

Comment: If the binary opens the file and doesn't close it you can check with `lsof /var/path/to/file`.

Comment: you could do a simple ls -la in the directory to see the date and if the date is recent it was modified recently

Comment: @SimpliFixed: and? How is that going to reveal which process has modified it?

Comment: I guess one could combine `lsof` with `inotifywait` if you need to catch the processes in the act of modifying the file - see for example [How to execute a command whenever a file changes?](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes). Otherwise maybe [auditd](https://serverfault.com/a/320718) ?

Comment: I tried using `losf` and `inotifywait` commands. But unable to see wich service/user has modified the file